# Netgear Terminal Access

Tags: router, hyperterminal

I am trying to use HyperTerminal to access my Netgear DGND4000 modem router. I setup a new connection using:

- Hostname = router IP address
- Port Number = 22
- Connect using = TCP/IP (SSH)

And it is coming up with the error: "Network error: connection refused".

The software hasn't asked me to enter username or password in, and I don't even know if this is the right way to get into a terminal interface with the router.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either it isn't a ssh server or you are hitting a firewall. Most devices of this class offer telnet servers or web interfaces, the better ones restrict these to the local network, but I have seen similar devices that when you enable telnet allow it from the public side. by the way does hypertermal actually support ssh these days?